# Linux one row from first file combine into multiple rows in second file, transpose denormalize

Tags: linux, awk, paste

File_1

```
Group   Country Lang
IT      USA     ENG
```

File_2

```
EMPID   STOREID
1001    1400
1002    1401
1003    1401
```

If I use

```
paste -d'\t' File_1 File_2
```

I get

```
Group^ICountry^ILang^IEMPID^ISTOREID$
IT^IUSA^IENG^I1001^I1400$
^I1002^I1401$   
^I1003^I1401$
```

While I am trying to get something like this

```
Group   Country Lang    EMPID   STOREID
IT  USA ENG     1001    1400
IT  USA ENG     1002    1401
IT  USA ENG     1003    1401
```

Please suggest

Comment: No thats output from vi with :list option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[FNR==1]=$0; next} {print a[FNR==1], $0}' file1 file2
Group   Country Lang    EMPID   STOREID
IT      USA     ENG     1001    1400
IT      USA     ENG     1002    1401
IT      USA     ENG     1003    1401
```

The above is just using the 1 or 0 result of a comparison "is this the first line of the file" (`FNR==1`) to index the array so you get the index 1 associated with the first line from file 1 when when it's the first line from file 2 and the index 0 associated with the 2nd line from file 1 for every other line of file 2. It'll behave the same way in any awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this task.

```bsh
awk '
    FNR == NR {buf[NR] = $0; next} 
    {print (FNR==1 ? buf[1] : buf[2]) "\t" $0}
' file1 file2
```

Save the header and the row while parsing the first file (`FNR==NR`) and print the appropriate prefix together with every row of the second file.

Output:

```
Group   Country Lang    EMPID   STOREID
IT      USA     ENG 1001    1400
IT      USA     ENG 1002    1401
IT      USA     ENG 1003    1401
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner with GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;nrow=FNR;next} NR==nrow+1 {print a[1],$0;next} {print a[2],$0}' data1 data2

Group   Country Lang EMPID   STOREID
IT      USA     ENG 1001    1400
IT      USA     ENG 1002    1401
IT      USA     ENG 1003    1401
```

with:

```
$ cat data1
Group   Country Lang
IT      USA     ENG
$ cat data2
EMPID   STOREID
1001    1400
1002    1401
1003    1401
```